# Adding two maps together

Tags: c++, gcc, ubuntu, gnu

I want to add two maps together with the following behavior.

if key exists -> add two key values together.

if key does not exist -> Insert pair to map.

I have looked at a few of the standard library algorithms. Namely transform, but doesn't seem to do what I want.

Taken from this [LINK](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/)

```
template < class InputIterator, class OutputIterator, class UnaryOperator >
  OutputIterator transform ( InputIterator first1, InputIterator last1,
                             OutputIterator result, UnaryOperator op )
{
  while (first1 != last1)
    *result++ = op(*first1++);  // or: *result++=binary_op(*first1++,*first2++);
  return result;
}
```

My thoughts from this where that I would only have one iterator from my second map when using and the appropriate functor

```
 *result++=binary_op(*first1++,*first2++);
```

Therefore I will not be able to loop over my second map to find the key value.

One thought was just to make my own algorithm with a subtle change.

```
template < class InputIterator, class ContainerType, class BinaryOperator >
  void myTransform ( InputIterator first1, InputIterator last1,
                               ContainerType cont2,  
                               BinaryOperator binary_op )
{
  while (first1 != last1)
    binary_op(first1++, cont2); //cont2 passed by reference 
}
```

I would then be able to use:

`cont2.find()` in my functor to search the whole map.

Here would be a more complete example of what I was thinking, but I seem to get a compiling error that I can not solve ( I am kind of guessing the BinaryOperator type...see below)?

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template < class InputIterator, class ContainerType, class BinaryOperator >
void myTransform ( InputIterator first1, InputIterator last1,
                 ContainerType &cont2, 
                 BinaryOperator binary_op )
{
  while (first1 != last1)
    binary_op(first1++, cont2); //cont2 passed by reference
}

template<class IteratorType, class ContainerType>
struct AddMapValues:
  std::binary_function<IteratorType, ContainerType, void>
{
  void operator()(IteratorType itr, ContainerType& cont)
  {
    if( cont.find(itr->first) != cont.end() ) cont[itr->first] = cont.find(itr->first).second + itr->second;
    else cont.insert( (*itr) );
  }
};


int main()
{
  typedef std::map<std::string, double> stringDoubleMap;
  typedef std::map<std::string, double>::iterator stringDoubleMapItr;
  typedef void (*ptrfnt)(stringDoubleMapItr, stringDoubleMap& );

  stringDoubleMap map1;
  stringDoubleMap map2;

  map1.insert( stringDoubleMap::value_type("Test1",1.0) );
  map1.insert( stringDoubleMap::value_type("Test2",2.0) );
  map1.insert( stringDoubleMap::value_type("Test3",3.0) );

  map2.insert( stringDoubleMap::value_type("Test1",1.0) );
  map2.insert( stringDoubleMap::value_type("Test2",2.0) );
  map2.insert( stringDoubleMap::value_type("Test3",3.0) );

  myTransform( map1.begin(), map1.end(),
               map2, 
               AddMapValues< stringDoubleMapItr, stringDoubleMap >() );

  return 0;

}
```

Here is my compiler error:

```
testingMapTransforms.cxx: In function ‘int main()’:

testingMapTransforms.cxx:52:85: error: no matching function for call to     ‘myTransform(std::map<std::basic_string<char>, double>::iterator, std::map<std::basic_string<char>, double>::iterator, stringDoubleMap&, std::map<std::basic_string<char>, double>::iterator, AddMapValues<std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, double> >, std::map<std::basic_string<char>, double> >)’

testingMapTransforms.cxx:52:85: note: candidate is:

testingMapTransforms.cxx:12:20: note: template<class InputIterator, class ContainerType, class   OutputIterator, class BinaryOperator> OutputIterator myTransform(InputIterator, InputIterator,  ContainerType, OutputIterator, BinaryOperator)
```

There seems to be another iterator coming from somewhere and the container type is not read properly?

Any ideas?

I am using

gcc - GNU project C and C++ compiler

with

Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5

Thanks

NOTE:

I have updated a working version of the code above in an answer. If you think I should just change the question code instead let me know. Not sure of the best practice

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't just do it by hand?

Comment: I think you do to many operations in one line; `*result++ = op(*first1++);` such code is hard to debug and it's not very readable.

Comment: @Spo1ler agree fully. let the compiler do its job optimizing and instead code so that other people can read it.

Comment: @Daniel Daranas I want my code to be flexible (not depend too much on types) and also efficient. A for loop would be an easy solution, but not what I am looking for as I am trying to learn "different" techniques.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a revised version of above. There were lots of bugs in the questions code, but this seems to work and is the same idea:

```
template < class InputIterator, class ContainerType, class BinaryOperator >
void myTransform ( InputIterator first1, InputIterator last1, ContainerType &cont2, BinaryOperator binary_op )
{
  while (first1 != last1)
    (*binary_op)(first1++, cont2); //cont2 passed by reference
}

template<class IteratorType, class ContainerType>
struct AddMapValues:
  std::binary_function<IteratorType, ContainerType, void>
{
  static void Add(IteratorType itr, ContainerType& cont)
  {
    cont[itr->first] += itr->second;
  }
};

int main()
{

  typedef std::map<std::string, double> stringDoubleMap;
  typedef std::map<std::string, double>::iterator stringDoubleMapItr;
  typedef void (*ptrfnt)(stringDoubleMapItr, stringDoubleMap& );

  stringDoubleMap map1;
  stringDoubleMap map2;

  map1.insert( stringDoubleMap::value_type("Test1",1.0) );
  map1.insert( stringDoubleMap::value_type("Test2",2.0) );
  map1.insert( stringDoubleMap::value_type("Test4",3.0) );

  map2.insert( stringDoubleMap::value_type("Test1",1.0) );
  map2.insert( stringDoubleMap::value_type("Test2",10.0) );
  map2.insert( stringDoubleMap::value_type("Test3",3.0) );

  myTransform( map1.begin(), map1.end(), map2, AddMapValues<stringDoubleMapItr, stringDoubleMap >::Add );

  for(stringDoubleMapItr itr = map2.begin(); itr != map2.end(); ++itr ){
    std::cout << "INFO: Key: " << itr->first << " | Value: " << itr->second  << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 12):

```
I want to add two maps together with the following behavior:
If key exists add two key values together.
If key does not exist. Insert pair to map.
```

I think a simple for loop would do what you want:

```
for(auto it = map2.begin(); it != map2.end(); ++it) map1[it->first] += it->second;
```

If the key exists, the value will be added to the existing one. If the key doesn't exist, `operator[]` will insert it and it's value will be default initialized (0.0 for `double`).

I don't think going for a generic function that would work on any container would be sensible here. The semantics of say vector's and map's insert() and operator[] are just too different.

Comment: @jrok the idea of myTransform template would be used for either map or vector and would use whatever functor you provide it. the AddMapValues functor would obviously only be for maps.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not readable. It is error prone.

Do it by hand, but doing one thing at a time. Do not mix incrementing pointers, dereferencing them, adding elements to a map and querying from another one all in the same line. It ends up in a mess.

Comment: I agree this code is not the most readable, but I took the code base from transform from the standard library so my thoughts were that this would have the best coding practice for the transform algorithm. In any case my compilation error comes from my template call.

Comment: @MWright: The rules for the implementation and the rules for user code are different.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do it with `transform`.  You have two containers,
you'll need two iterator pairs, and you'll need to advance them
separately when an element is only in one of them.  The two sequence
version of `transform` advances them in lockstep.

It shouldn't be too hard to do by hand.  Something like the following, 
perhaps:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, std::double> Map

Map
addValues( Map const& m1, Map const& m2 )
{
    Map results;
    Map::const_iterator i1 = m1.begin();
    Map::const_iterator i2 = m2.begin();
    while ( i1 != m1.end() && i2 != m2.end() ) {
        if ( i1->first < i2->first ) {
            results.insert( results.end(), *i1 );
            ++ i1;
        } else if ( i2->first < i1->first ) {
            results.insert( results.end(), *i2 );
            ++ i2;
        } else {
            results.insert( results.end(),
                            Map::value_type( i1->first, i1->second + i2->second ) );
            ++ i1;
            ++ i2;
        }
    }
    results.insert( i1, m1.end() );
    results.insert( i2, m2.end() );
    return results;
}
```

(I'd get it working like this first, before making it a template.)